# Is there a way to disable keyCode function?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've created a Tetris game that is made up of 200 squares (10 x 20) and the starting position for each 'tetromino' is in position 4.

The game is operated by using the four keycodes up, down, left and right, the player scores 10 points for each row cleared. The user is not able to move right when the shape is placed far right, and vice versa for a shape placed on the direct opposite.

Now, when another existing tetromino is in starting position 4 the screen will display 'Game over' and I have disabled the all the buttons on the screen apart from the restart button which will reload the windows.

How do I disable the four keycodes when it's game over so the user can't move the shape of the tetromino?

So far have this on my project

```
  // Game over
  function gameOver() {
    if(
      current.some(index => 
        squares[currentPosition + index].classList.contains('taken')
      )
    ) {
      scoreDisplay.innerHTML = `You scored ${score} points. <br> Game Over.`;
      document.getElementById("start-button").disabled = true;
      document.getElementById("play-button").disabled = true;

      clearInterval(timerId);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Set up a handler on the `keypress` event and check for those keys. If one of those keys is being pressed, do nothing.

Comment: Can you post your code where you set the key down event listener? You should probably just completely remove it, or at least disable it, in the `gameOver` function.

Comment: this is the github link https://github.com/Edwardleung1/tetris/blob/master/app.js

Comment: Why don't you check the `timerId`? It seems that you are using that to determine if the game is currently running. So you could wrap your control logic with an `if` and just not handle the event if the `timerId` is null.